# Curl python + token bearer + query sql

Tags: python, sql

**I'm trying to create a curl in python to connect to a swagger api and download the data to a csv.

This is the first time I use Python, before I had curl in PHP, but I needed to change

This is the script**

```
# Import necessary modules
import pycurl

import urllib.parse

query = """
SELECT min({cart_pai.pk}) FROM {cart as carrinho JOIN cart AS cart_pai ON {carrinho.parent} = {cart_pai.pk}}
"""
safe_string = urllib.parse.quote_plus(query)

url = """
https://api.cokecxf-commercec1-p1-public.model-t.cc.commerce.ondemand.com/clarowebservices/v2/claro/flexiblesearch/export/search/getAsCsv?
"""
# Define the headers
headers = ['Authorization: Bearer 4DmQkomKs0z845705JIlfW-hhNg']

# Initialize a Curl object
c = pycurl.Curl()


# Set the URL to send the request to
c.setopt(c.URL, url + safe_string)

# Set the HTTPHEADER option with the headers
c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, headers)

# Perform the request
c.perform()

# Close the Curl object to free system resources
c.close()
```

Comment: Could you please format your code?

Comment: import requests
import urllib.parse


query = """
SELECT min({cart_pai.pk}) FROM {cart as carrinho JOIN cart AS cart_pai ON {carrinho.parent} = {cart_pai.pk}}
"""

url = """
https://api.cokecxf-commercec1-p1-public.model-t.cc.commerce.ondemand.com/clarowebservices/v2/claro/flexiblesearch/export/search/getAsCsv?
"""

safe_string = urllib.parse.quote_plus(query)

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer 4DmQkomKs0z845705JIlfW-hhNg'
}

response = requests.get(url + safe_string, headers=headers)
print(response)

Comment: And the first time I post a code here, I'm going to look for where to format it lol

Comment: I managed to format

Comment: (a) I don't see a question here. Is there a problem? Are you getting an error, or unexpected behavior? (b) In your question you are using `pycurl`, but in your comment above you appear to be using `requests`. Which is your actual code?

Comment: (a) The error reported c.perform()
pycurl.error: (3, 'URL rejected: Malformed input to a URL function')

(b) in these examples I'm trying with pycurl, but I have an example with request also without success.

Comment: Good, but you haven't asked anything. Without a question we cannot provide any answer

Comment: My friends, thank you very much for your help, I managed to solve it, the error was in the url+sql

Answer (score 0):

My friends, thank you very much for your help, I managed to solve it, the error was in the concatenation of the url + SQL